# WorkerRole VM Size at Deployment Time

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services, azure-deployment

From what I know, there is an option to provide VM size in Cloud Service Package using Role Settings.
But this information is required prior to build.
Is there a way I can decide VM size at the time of deployment?
I have a requirement of a worker role running in different regions and in some regions the load is not much so I want to use a lower size VM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to do so because VM size is defined in `csdef` file which gets bundled into your package.

Instead of relying on vertical scalability (i.e. choosing different VM size for different regions based on the load), may I recommend you look at horizontal scalability (i.e. choosing different number of VM instances for different regions based on load). The benefits I see with this approach:

- Instance count is specified in `cscfg` file, thus you can build the package but deploy your application to run with different instance count based on the region.
- Again because instance count is specified in `cscfg` file, you can scale up/down easily based on your load pattern without having the need to redeploy your code.

Comment: This answer is 3 years old, and I dearly hope it's not still true. Having VM size effectively hardwired into the application is ridiculous: why should I have to have the same size VM for my QA environment as I have in production?

Comment: Sadly, it is still true.

Comment: Alas! I just received confirmation of this from Azure support. The insanity continues!